# Is making accounting software for handling e.g. interest haram?

Tags: halal-haram, riba, software

If I make software that deals with credit, debit, assets, liabilities, equity, and stuff like that, and also for recording monthly payments, will that be haram?  I ask this because people can choose to put in interest as monthly payments so is that going to indirectly help them record interest?

Answer (score 1):

From the below mentioned haith it is clear that Muslims should not be involved in any aspect of riba. As it is one of the sure ways to Jahnam.

From Jabir : The Prophet, may cursed the receiver and the payer of interest, the one who records it and the two witnesses to the transaction and said: "They are all alike [in guilt]." (Muslim, Kitab al-Musaqat, Bab la'ni akili al-riba wa mu'kilihi; also in Tirmidhi and Musnad Ahmad)

one of many hadith thats indicates that interest is haraam:

From Abu Hurayrah : The Prophet,  said: "God would be justified in not allowing four persons to enter paradise or to taste its blessings: he who drinks habitually, he who takes riba, he who usurps an orphan's property without right, and he who is undutiful to his parents." (Mustadrak al-Hakim, Kitab al-Buyu')